# How to use the CSRT Tracker correctly to track objects in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tracking

I've tried to use the `CSRT` tracker from `OpenCv V4.5.1` to track faces inside video sequences, at the end of **some** videos I get this error which I can't understand why does it happen!

- I'm using [AVDIAR dataset](http://crowley-coutaz.fr/jlc/Courses/2020/GVR.VO/AVDIAR-videos+BBoxs)
- can you please advise me how to use the tracker correctly with Viola-Jones face detector?

> Note: wen I used `KCF` Tracker things worked perfectly! `tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()`

```
---> 12     tracker.init(frame, myBox)
error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-r2ue8w6k\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:811:
error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows 
in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'
```

The code I'm using to use the tracker is:

```py
def tracking(frame, bbox):
    """
    Parameters:
    @param: frame: nd-array frame from video sequence.
    @param: bbox: bounding box
    """
    [x0, y0, x1, y1] = bbox
    myBox = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
    tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    tracker.init(frame, myBox)
    # Update tracker
    ok, box = tracker.update(frame)
    if ok:
        [x0, x1] = [x0, x1] if x1>x0 else [x1, x0]
        [y0, y1] = [y0, y1] if y1>y0 else [y1, y0]
        result = [x0, y0, x1, y1]
        return result
    print("tracking No result ", bbox)
    return bbox
```

The function that is calling the tracking is:

```py
def violaJones(xmlPath, videoPath, verbose=False):
    """
    Parameters:
    @param: xmlPath: string, path to the Haar_Cascade xml file.
    @param: videoPath: string, Video Full Path.
    @param: verbose
    """
    # print(videoPath)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    bboxes = {}
    nb_frame = 0
    # Blue color in BGR 
    color = [(255, 128, 128),(128, 255, 128),(128, 128, 255), (128,255,255),(255,128,255), (255,255,128)]
    # Line thickness of 2 px 
    thickness = 2
    # max numer of people
    maxID = 0
    track = [None]*10
    # Read until video is completed
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # 
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
            # gauss = skinThresh(frame)
            # Cascade Classifier
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(xmlPath)
            detected_faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gauss.astype(np.uint8), 1.2, 4)
            id = 0
            for (x0,y0,w,h) in detected_faces:
                id += 1
                maxID = maxID if maxID > id else id
                x1 = x0 + w
                y1 = y0 + h
                # Tracking
                track[id-1] = tracking(frame, [x0, y0, x1, y1])

            for ID in range(maxID):
                if track[ID] is not None:
                    bboxes[str(nb_frame)+str(ID+1)] = np.array(tracking(frame, track[ID]))
                    # Draw Annotations
                    if verbose:
                        [xx0, yy0, xx1, yy1] = track[ID]
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xx0,yy0),(xx1,yy1), color[ID], thickness)
            # show
            if verbose:
                cv2.imshow("Viola_Jones", frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        # Break the loop
        else:
            break
        nb_frame +=1
    # Closes all the frames
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # When everything done, release the video capture object
    cap.release()
    return bboxes
```

The last values of the print function before the error are:

| x0 | y0 | x1 | y1 | Frame Shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 574 | 46 | 634 | 106 | (450, 720, 3) |
| 600 | 35 | 663 | 98 | (450, 720, 3) |
| 600 | 35 | 663 | 98 | (450, 720, 3) |
| 600 | 35 | 663 | 98 | (450, 720, 3) |
| 600 | 35 | 663 | 98 |  |

Comment: show the rest of the code. `frame` is probably empty because everyone's using VideoCapture wrong.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz rest of the code added.

Comment: this code has too many things wrong with it. you instantiate tracker instances anew for every frame. you should do that once and keep the tracker instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to declare a tracker for each object, and initiate that tracker once as following:

#### Tracker Function

```py
def tracking(frame, bbox, tracker, Init):
    """
    Parameters:
    @param: frame: nd-array frame from video sequence.
    @param: bbox: bounding box
    @param: tracker: tracker from OpenCV such as KCF or CSRT
    """
    [x0, y0, x1, y1] = bbox
    myBox = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
    if(not Init):
        # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
        tracker.init(frame, myBox)
        Init = True
    # Update tracker
    ok, box = tracker.update(frame)
    if ok:
        [x0, x1] = [x0, x1] if x1>x0 else [x1, x0]
        [y0, y1] = [y0, y1] if y1>y0 else [y1, y0]
        result = [x0, y0, x1, y1]
        return result
    return bbox
```

### Viola-Jones

```py
def violaJones(xmlPath, videoPath, verbose=False):
    """
    Parameters:
    @param: xmlPath: string, path to the Haar_Cascade xml file.
    @param: videoPath: string, Video Full Path.
    @param: verbose, bolean to visualize the results.
    """
    # print(videoPath)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    bboxes = {}
    nb_frame = 0
    # Blue color in BGR 
    color = [(255, 128, 128),(128, 255, 128),(128, 128, 255), (128,255,255),(255,128,255), (255,255,128)]
    # Line thickness of 2 px 
    thickness = 2
    # max numer of people
    maxID = 0
    track = [None]*10

    trackInit = [False]*5

    tracker1 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    tracker2 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    tracker3 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    tracker4 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    tracker5 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

    trackers = [tracker1, tracker2, tracker3, tracker4, tracker5]
    # tracker1 = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
    # tracker2 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

    # Read until video is completed
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # 
            # gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            # gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
            gauss = skinThresh(frame)
            # Cascade Classifier
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(xmlPath)
            detected_faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gauss, 1.2, 4)
            id = 0
            for (x0,y0,w,h) in detected_faces:
                id += 1
                maxID = maxID if maxID > id else id
                x1 = x0 + w
                y1 = y0 + h
                # Detection
                track[id-1] = [x0, y0, x1, y1]

            for ID in range(maxID):
                #Tracking
                if track[ID] is not None:
                    bboxes[str(nb_frame)+str(ID+1)] = np.array(tracking(frame, track[ID], trackers[ID], trackInit[ID]))
                    trackInit[ID] = True
                    # Draw Annotations
                    if verbose:
                        [xx0, yy0, xx1, yy1] = track[ID]
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xx0,yy0),(xx1,yy1), color[ID], thickness)
            # show
            if verbose:
                cv2.imshow("Viola_Jones", frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        # Break the loop
        else:
            break
        nb_frame +=1
    # When everything done, release the video capture object
    cap.release()
    # Closes all the frames
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return bboxes
```

Comment: I suppose you only consider a fixed number of faces, where no new ones come or old ones vanishes? Otherwise the ID will fail right? Also, there's no data association in this code right(enlighten me if I'm wrong...)?

Comment: @dexter2406  fixed **maximum** number of faces, there still some serious issues in mapping between ID and faces right.